# CSS - My border-bottom resizes when I resize my browser

Tags: css, browser, border

I use a border-bottom on my navigation div, which is 100% wide. When I resize my browser window, the border-bottom suddenly gets cut off to te size that I just resized my browser to.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

**my css:**

```
#nav {
clear: both;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 3px #ff6600 solid;
}

#nav ul {
margin: 0 0 0 670px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;

}

#nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}
```

**My html:**

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
               <li><a href="hobby's">Hobby's</a></li>
               <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer!

By looking at other posts, someone said that the 100% width only applies to the 'viewport' of the screen. So thats why the div gets cut off.

To solve this you have to add a **min-width in pixels** to the body in css.

So in my case I changed it to:

```
body {

min-width: 1439px;

}
```

Comment: I'm using a bottom border to underline items in a navbar and it was writing on top of the text when the page was made smaller. This fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning a margin left value of 670px, you are effectively setting a width to your page.

Thus, if the page resizes to something smaller than that (or that plus the text in the list items), it will appear that things get cut off because they extend beyond the frame of the window.

In order to have it be completely dynamic on width based on the window size, you'd need to have absolutely no hard-coded set values.  You could try using a % for the margin, or you could use an alternate css style based on the width of the window.

Comment: The problem is I want my navigation to stay at that exact spot, because some kind of logo will come to the left. When I change the margin to a %, my navigation moves along to the left when resizing the window. I really don't know another way to keep it there though.. 
Maybe I could make another div that looks like a border but I'm not sure if it will be the same

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a little hard to get the best of both worlds.  Ultimately, if you want to be able to have your browser resize without the possibility of something being cut off, the whole page needs to be able to resize.  This means that the navigation would have to move, and likely would have to change the size of the logo.

Comment: You could jury rig it by removing the border-bottom from the "nav" div and adding a new div under the "nav" div with that border bottom.  It's not really the right way of doing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

i think this way is better

change

```
#nav ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 670px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to

```
#nav ul {
    float: right; // instead of margin: 0 0 0 670px;
    margin: 0; //reset ul default properties 
    padding: 0; //reset ul default properties 
}
```

---

also change this

```
#nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}
```

to

```
#nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px; // padding only for left and right, just use line-height instead of padding-top and padding-bottom
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
    line-height: 40px; // same value as navigation height (#nav) , no need to use padding for top and bottom
}
```

Comment: By removing the margin-left and white-space: nowrap, my navigation ul moves along to the left when I resize my window. I really want my navigation to stay to the far right, so you have to horizontally scroll to it.